# PictureBox plays gif twice

Tags: c#, winforms, animated-gif

I'm trying to create add a super simple animated gif to a PictureBox control in WinForms.

And I'm having this super weird issue, that the gif runs twice, even though the gif is created to only run once.

This is the code. I tried adding it through Resources and the Design window, same result.

```
    private string gif = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"resources\lock.gif";

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // picturebox is set to disabled in properties
        pbxImage.ImageLocation = gif;
        pbxImage.Load();
        pbxImage.Enabled = true;
        
    }
```

I was thinking this would be super simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm relatively new to WinForms so I'm guessing there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @Austin Yeah - checked, and rechecked with Photoshop - even edited the gif and re-exported it. Same result.

Comment: Try with another gif - see if you get the same result. 
That experiment should reveal if it's your WinForms or your gif that is the problem

Comment: I tried both answers, without any success. In the latter - I tried using the first frame as my initial frame, but to no avail. It just insists on playing the whole .gif twice.

I really over an hour of research trying to figure out why. I was hoping there was some setting I forgot or didn't know about. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: @JensKloster - I tried with several, same result.

Comment: Shot in the dark, try using the `OnShown(...)` override instead.

Comment: @LarsTech Giving that a shot.

Comment: @LarsTech No dice, unfortunately.

Comment: [How to play a GIF animation to the last Frame, then stop the animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305196/7444103) (C# code in the second snippet) - You can also control how many times the animation loops.

Comment: @Jimi - I can make something of this, this actually stops my gif, though in a super weird place. Stops it at frame 4 somehow. But I can work with that.

Comment: @Austin - I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Austin - No dice. This shouldn't be that hard, should it? I even tried with a gif of my own making, same result.

Comment: This might be a sign that the GIF is not 100% compatible. Try with another (e.g., download one from Google Images) to see what happens.

Comment: @Jimi - I tried several already, even made one quickly, same result.

Comment: Well, I tested a few myself when I wrote that code and all worked as intended. Did you follow the *instructions* there? For example, start the animation using a Button as described (for testing), or in the `Form.Load` or `Form.Shown` handlers.

Comment: @Jimi - Yeah, I did. Project is targeting .net 6 though. I'm creating a project targeting .net 5, seeing if that fixes it.

Trust me, I'm super confused. I know this question looks super simple, and it should be. I spent a lot of time reseaching before actually asking a question here.

Tried OnLoad, OnShown, OnActivated (On the PictureBox) - even tried from a different thread.

Comment: Same problem here.I make a gif with repeat times 1 and it plays 2 times inside pictureBox. Cannot find a working solution...